# Data change not reflected when INotifyPropertyChanged is not implemented

Tags: c#, datagridview, inotifypropertychanged

first see the below code which works fine and when we update entity then change is automatically reflected in grid but the moment i comment this `INotifyPropertyChanged` and all other code related to notify property change then grid is not getting the change.

so i like to know what kind of role is played by `INotifyPropertyChanged` ?
how `INotifyPropertyChanged` communicate with grid to show or reflect the chnage?
please help me to understand the communication between `grid and INotifyPropertyChanged` . thanks

```
namespace PatternSearch
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnBindData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingList<Car> cars = new BindingList<Car>();

            cars.Add(new Car("Ford", "Mustang", 1967));
            cars.Add(new Car("Shelby AC", "Cobra", 1965));
            cars.Add(new Car("Chevrolet", "Corvette Sting Ray", 1965));

            dataGridView1.DataSource = cars;
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.DataSource != null)
            {
                BindingList<Car> cars = dataGridView1.DataSource as BindingList<Car>;
                cars.Where(d => d.Make == "Ford").First().Make = "My Ford000";
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Grid has no data");
        }
    }


    public class Car : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _make;
        private string _model;
        private int _year;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Car(string make, string model, int year)
        {
            _make = make;
            _model = model;
            _year = year;
        }

        public string Make
        {
            get { return _make; }
            set
            {
                _make = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Make");
            }
        }

        public string Model
        {
            get { return _model; }
            set
            {
                _model = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Model");
            }
        }

        public int Year
        {
            get { return _year; }
            set
            {
                _year = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Year");
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

### here is the code where i comment INotifyPropertyChanged and all its related code

```
namespace PatternSearch
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnBindData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingList<Car> cars = new BindingList<Car>();

            cars.Add(new Car("Ford", "Mustang", 1967));
            cars.Add(new Car("Shelby AC", "Cobra", 1965));
            cars.Add(new Car("Chevrolet", "Corvette Sting Ray", 1965));

            dataGridView1.DataSource = cars;
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.DataSource != null)
            {
                BindingList<Car> cars = dataGridView1.DataSource as BindingList<Car>;
                cars.Where(d => d.Make == "Ford").First().Make = "My Ford000";
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Grid has no data");
        }
    }


    public class Car //: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _make;
        private string _model;
        private int _year;

        //public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Car(string make, string model, int year)
        {
            _make = make;
            _model = model;
            _year = year;
        }

        public string Make
        {
            get { return _make; }
            set
            {
                _make = value;
                //this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Make");
            }
        }

        public string Model
        {
            get { return _model; }
            set
            {
                _model = value;
                //this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Model");
            }
        }

        public int Year
        {
            get { return _year; }
            set
            {
                _year = value;
                //this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Year");
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            //if (PropertyChanged != null)
            //    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface exposes a `PropertyChanged` event. The grid subscribes to this event to know when the value of a property is changed. Otherwise, the grid (or any other UI control) would have no way to know when the value has changed, short of pooling it.

Comment: @KooKiz it is "polling" not "pooling" (quite a difference)

Comment: @DrKoch I wish there was a browser extension preventing me to post on StackOverflow before finishing my coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid checks if the object implements INotifyPropertyChanged. If it does, it subscribes to the PropertyChanged event (the only member of the interface) to be notified of the name of the properties that have the value changed.

A better NotifyPropertyChanged implementation would be:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

and a property would look like:

```
public int Year
{
    get { return _year; }
    set
    {
        _year = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

In this way, the code would be more bug proof to property name refactoring.

Comment: i want to implement MVVM in winform project. so can u guide me how to bind controls with data like textbox, dropdown and other in winform form following MVVM pattern.

Comment: i got a good link for [CallerMemberName] info  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh534540.aspx.

Comment: @Mou As msdn states, it's an attribute. You can use the CallerMemberName attribute to avoid specifying the member name as a String argument to the called method. By using this technique, you avoid the problem that Rename Refactoring doesn't change the String values.